# How copy file automatically bewteen 2 buckets with two different projects gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, storage, bucket

Actually i use that command , and it works well :

```
gsutil cp gs:/bucket1/file.xml gs://bucket2/destination_folder
```

(bucket1 is in project1 in GCP and bucket2 is in another project in GCP)

But i would like to do that command every day at 9am, how can i do that on my GCP project in a easy way ?

Edit  : It will copy the file over and over each day from the source bucket to the destination bucket( the two buckets are in a different project each). (actually when the file arrive in the destination bucket, it is consume and ingest in bigquery automatically , i just want to trigg my command gsutil and stop to do it manually each morning )

(except the method with Data transfert because i have not the right of the source project so i cannot activate the service account for data transfert , i have only the rights on destination project.)

Bests regards,

Actually i can copy a file from a bucket into another bucket into a specfic folder (RQ : the 2 buckets are on the same gcp project)
I don't arrive to use the second method with a gs://

EDIT 2:

```
import base64
import  sys
import urllib.parse
# Imports the Google Cloud client library , dont forget the requirement or else it's ko
from google.cloud import storage


def copy_blob(
    bucket_name ="prod-data", blob_name="test.csv", destination_bucket_name = "prod-data-f", destination_blob_name ="channel_p"
):
    """Copies a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    bucket_name = "prod-data"
    blob_name = "test.csv"
    destination_bucket_name = "prod-data-f"
    destination_blob_name = "channel_p/test.csv"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob("huhu/"+blob_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
    )

# Second Method (KO)
#
#   client = storage.Client()
#   with open('gs://prod-data-f/channelp.xml','wb') as file_obj:
#       client.download_blob_to_file(
#           'gs://pathsource/somefolder/channelp.xml', file_obj)
#
# End of second Method

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
        )
    )
```

Comment: Do you use your user credential to perform this `gsutil`  operation? If so, do you also have a service account which can read in the source project to write in the destination one? (I understood that the destination project isn't a concern, you have the right on it)

Comment: Is your goal to copy one bucket to another "over and over" or is your goal to "synchronize" two buckets in one direction or to mirror them? Edit your question with details.

Comment: Hi, when i execute my command, i get this message : 

"Authorize Cloud Shell
bq is requesting your credentials to make a GCP API call.
Click to authorize this and future calls that require your credentials."

Then i click on accept and it move the file

Comment: Your comment does not answer my questions. Your question states `gsutil`, your comment states `bq`. Edit your question with actual details.

Comment: @JohnHanley, the message appears when i execute my command gsutil on cloud shell on gcp. when i execute the same command a second time , it' doesnt appear anymore.
I edit my post with some precisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i was seeking (it works for me when i test):

Main.py

```
import base64
import os
import sys
import json
import uuid
import logging
from time import sleep
from flask import request
from random import uniform
from google.cloud import firestore
from google.cloud.exceptions import Forbidden, NotFound
from google.cloud import storage

# set retry deadline to 60s
DEFAULT_RETRY = storage.retry.DEFAULT_RETRY.with_deadline(60)

def Move2FinalBucket(data, context):

#    if 'data' in event:
#        name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
#    else:
#        name = 'NO_DATA'
#        print('Message {}!'.format(name))


    # Get cache source bucket
    cache_bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket('nameofmysourcebucket', timeout=540, retry=DEFAULT_RETRY)

    # Get source file to copy
    blob2transfer = cache_bucket.blob('uu/oo/pp/filename.csv')

    # Get cache destination bucket
    destination_bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket('nameofmydestinationbucket', timeout=540, retry=DEFAULT_RETRY)

    # Get destination file
    new_file = destination_bucket.blob('kk/filename.csv')

    #rewrite into new_file
    new_file.rewrite(blob2transfer, timeout=540, retry=DEFAULT_RETRY)
```

requirement.txt

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
#google-cloud-storage==1.22.0
google-cloud-storage
google-cloud-firestore
google-api-core
flask==1.1.4
```

Dont forget to add a service account with the right Storage admin on this CF and it will works.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Data transfer is obviously the right tool for doing this, but since you cannot use it, there are alternative solutions.

One of them is to copy files using a Cloud Function (you can use [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625349)), and trigger each day at 9am that Cloud Function using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating). Cloud Function can also be triggered by a Pub/Sub message.

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what i seek, i will try that solution solution